# Is it possible to transfer a Windows "Home to Pro" licence key to another computer?

Tags: windows, downgrade, licensing

My computer came pre-installed with Windows 8 Home, the licence key being baked into the BIOS. I have since upgraded via the Microsoft-offered free channels to Windows 8.1 Home, and now Windows 10 Home.

As Windows 10 [still accepts](http://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-free-upgrade-is-still-available-using-windows-7-and-8-product-keys/) Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 keys, I have recently purchased a **[Windows 8 Pro Pack](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Windows-Standard-Pack-Upgrade-Product/dp/B00844OH4Y)** to upgrade my Windows 10 installation from Home to Pro (though even if it doesn't work, I'll reinstall Windows 8 and work my way up again).

My question is, since my Home key has an OEM origin, yet my Home-to-Pro-upgrade-only key is retail, if I want to sell my laptop in future, would I be able to revert to the OEM Home licence and take the Pro-upgrade key with me to a new computer?

Comment: You "My question is, since my Home key has an OEM origin, yet my Home-to-Pro-upgrade-only key is retail, if I want to sell my laptop in future, would I be able to revert to the OEM Home licence and take the Pro-upgrade key with me to a new computer?" - Technically speaking your not even eligible for the upgrade, so technically speaking if you ignore that fact, your Professional license has transfer rights

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft will tell you](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activation) that your Windows 10 Pro upgrade is a digital license.  As a result, if you ever need to `Reset` or `Refresh` your PC after the upgrade, it will install Windows 10 Pro:

[image: Activation]

But your upgrade is only good on one PC:

> The upgrade will be licensed only to a single PC. So, if you purchased a retail Windows 10 Home license and you purchase a Windows 10 Pro upgrade, that upgrade will only work on a single computer. While you’re entitled to move the original Windows 10 Home license to another computer, that Windows 10 Pro upgrade won’t follow you to another PC.

(Source:  [How to Upgrade From Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Professional](http://www.howtogeek.com/234946/how-to-upgrade-from-windows-10-home-to-windows-10-professional/))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The one you highlighted doesn't apply in my case, as my upgrade will have been from a retail box containing a Product Key Card. My situation is exactly the opposite of the How-To Geek article: my Home licence is non-retail and my Pro licence is retail.