# Can I transfer a Windows 10 Pro License to another PC

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have recently bought a new PC that has Windows 10 Home and would like to upgrade it using the license on my old Laptop which is Windows 10 Pro.

I'm very confused about if it is transferable. I have been through a upgrade from Windows 8 on my old laptop and if I had a key, I believe it has been lost since.

Running the `slmgr -dli` command in a CMD window will yield a popup saying it is a retail version, suggesting it is transferable. However I seem to see that the key is a generic Windows 10 Pro Key.
[image]
Also I wasn't sure what the deal with the "Digital License". As the pro license says its linked to my Microsoft account.

[image]

So would this mean it is transferable?

I've attempted to try find out what this all means but have gotten a bit confused with the licensing of Windows.

Comment: Yes since it is a Retail license. I think you can do this 3 times before you have to call Microsoft to activate.

Comment: Similar question>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1173780/is-it-possible-to-transfer-a-windows-home-to-pro-licence-key-to-another-comput?rq=1

Comment: Your Windows 10 license you received when you upgrade from Windows 8 cannot be transferred to another machine.  However, in theory you could install Windows 8 Retail on your new machine, and upgrade that to Windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I transfer a Windows 10 licence to my new PC if it was upgraded from a retail licence?](https://superuser.com/questions/980204/can-i-transfer-a-windows-10-licence-to-my-new-pc-if-it-was-upgraded-from-a-retai)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a *Retail* edition of Windows 10 Pro, as you've shown in the screenshots, then yes, in theory that should be transferable to new hardware. If it is linked to your Microsoft account then you may be able to login with your Microsoft account on the new machine and perform the activation that way.

I think if you have a digital licence, this doesn't include a product key. The product key listed via `slmgr` might just display a generic one in that instance.

Did you end up trying it? How did it go?